# 2-dimensional moment generating function of (X, logX)

Tags: probability, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions

I'm having trouble with starting and completing this question:
$X$ is a [Gamma-distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) random variable, $X\sim\Gamma(k,\theta)$. What is the (two-dimensional) moment generating function
of $(X, \log X)$?

It turns out the answer is supposed to be $\psi_{x,logX} (t,u)=\Gamma(p+u)/\Gamma(p) * a^u/(1-at)^{p+u}$

Comment: You should show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $2$-dimensional moment-generating function is given by:

$$ M_X(u,v) = \mathbb{E}[e^{uX+v\log X}] = \mathbb{E}[X^v e^{uX}]=\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^v e^{ux} \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)\,\theta^k} x^{k-1}\,e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}\,dx $$
hence:

$$ M_X(u,v) = \frac{\Gamma(k+v)}{\theta^k\,\Gamma(k)\left(\frac{1}{\theta}-u\right)^{k+v}}$$
provided that $v>-k$ and $u<\frac{1}{\theta}$.